# Faithful 2 dimensional representation of the 2 dimensional nonabelian Lie algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

So, let's say that $L$ is the unique 2-dimensional nonabelian lie algebra with basis $\{x,y\}$ and $[x,y]=x$

Suppose now that $V$ is a faithful two-dimensional representation of $L$. I've already shown that $V$ has a 1-dimensional irreducible submodule spanned by an element I called $v$. I am now going to extend $v$ to a basis of $V$, by an element called $w$.

I'm trying to show that the matrix of $x$ concerning this basis is of the form

$$A = \left( \begin{matrix} 0 & b \\ 0 & 0 \\  \end{matrix} \right)$$

where $b$ is nonzero.

I'm rotten at math... just a hobbyist with some spare time on his hands hoping to get walked through this.. thanks in advance!!

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $Vect(v)$ is invariant, $x.v=dv, y.v=ev,$ where $d,e$ are elements of the field. $ x.v=[x,y].v=x.(y.v)-(y.(x.v))=edv-dev=0$.

We deduce that the kernel of the action of $x$ is not trivial, since this action is not trivial, the dimension of its image is $1$, let $w$ be a generator of the image, $x.w=bw, b\neq 0$, remark that we do not have $x.w'=b'w'$ for every element $w'$ such that $(v,w')$ is a basis. for example, consider $w'=v+w$, $x.w'=x.(v+w)=bw=b(w'-v)=bw'-bv$.

Comment: on the second line, why do you have $x.v = [x,y].v$??

Comment: @FireFenix777 Because you have $[x,y]=x$ on the second line of your post.